# proper class hierarchy for 2D and 3D vectors

Tags: oop, scala, architecture, hierarchy

I want to have a general vector abstract class / trait that specifies certain methods, e.g.:

```
trait Vec 
{
  def +(v:Vec):Vec
  def *(d:Double):Vec

  def dot(v:Vec):Double
  def norm:Double
}
```

I want to have `Vec2D` and `Vec3D` extend `Vec`:

```
class Vec2D extends Vec { /* implementation */ }
class Vec3D extends Vec { /* implementation */ }
```

But how can I, for instance, make it so that `Vec2D` can only be added to other `Vec2D` and not to `Vec3D`?

Right now I'm just implementing `Vec2D` and `Vec3D` without a common `Vec` ancestor, but this is getting tedious with duplicate code. I have to implement all my geometry classes that depend on these classes (e.g. `Triangle`, `Polygon`, `Mesh`, ...) twice, once for `Vec2D` and again for `Vec3D`.

I see the java implementations: `javax.vecmath.Vector2d` and `javax.vecmath.Vector3d` do not have a common ancestor. What's the reason for this? Is there a way to overcome it in scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776864/scala-self-type-value-is-not-a-member-error/4777195#4777195), the most useful way of designing the base trait involves both the [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773611/proper-class-hierarchy-for-2d-and-3d-vectors/4773642#4773642) *and* the [self-type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773611/proper-class-hierarchy-for-2d-and-3d-vectors/4773855#4773855).

```
trait Vec[T <: Vec[T]] { this: T =>
  def -(v: T): T
  def *(d: Double): T

  def dot(v: T): Double
  def norm: Double = math.sqrt(this dot this)
  def dist(v: T) = (this - v).norm
}
```

Without the self-type, it is not possible to call `this.dot(this)` as `dot` expects a `T`; therefore we need to enforce it with the annotation.

On the other hand, without CRTP, we’ll fail to call `norm` on `(this - v)` as `-` returns a `T` and thus we need to make sure that our type `T` has this method, e.g. declare that `T` *is a* `Vec[T]`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use self types:

```
trait Vec[T] { self:T =>
  def +(v:T):T
  def *(d:Double):T

  def dot(v:T):Double
  def norm:Double
}

class Vec2D extends Vec[Vec2D] { /* implementation */ }
class Vec3D extends Vec[Vec3D] { /* implementation */ }
```

But if both implementations are very similar, you could also try to abstract over the Dimension.

```
sealed trait Dimension
case object Dim2D extends Dimension
case object Dim3D extends Dimension

sealed abstract class Vec[D <: Dimension](val data: Array[Double]) { 

  def +(v:Vec[D]):Vec[D] = ...
  def *(d:Double):Vec[D] = ...

  def dot(v:Vec[D]):Double = ...
  def norm:Double = math.sqrt(data.map(x => x*x).sum)
}

class Vec2D(x:Double, y:Double) extends Vec[Dim2D.type](Array(x,y))
class Vec3D(x:Double, y:Double, z:Double) extends Vec[Dim3D.type](Array(x,y,z))
```

Of course it depends on how you want to represent the data, and if you want to have mutable or immutable instances. And for "real world" applications you should consider http://code.google.com/p/simplex3d/

Comment: Self types allow you to refer to `this`, whereas the CRTP pattern in Dario's answer does not.

Comment: @dsg: What do you mean you can’t refer to `this` with CRTP?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about the proper Scala syntax, but you can implement the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), i.e. define the actual type through a generic parameter.

```
trait Vec[V <: Vec[V]] {
  def +(v:V):V
  ...
}

class Vec2D extends Vec[Vec2D] { }
class Vec3D extends Vec[Vec3D] { }

class Polygon[V <: Vec[V]] {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Spot on. Syntax is correct and everything! I guess java does not support this (otherwise what's the deal with `javax.vecmath`)?

Comment: Actually, I guess java does support this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382915/what-does-this-java-generics-paradigm-do-and-what-is-it-called

Answer (score 2):

There is a big problem with having a common ancestor with CRTP pattern on JVM. When you execute the same abstract code with different implementations, JVM will de-optimize the code (no inlining + virtual calls). You will not notice this if you only test with Vec3D, but if you test with both Vec2D and Vec3D you will see a huge drop in performance. Moreover, Escape Analysis cannot be applied to the de-optimize code (no scalar replacement, no elimitation of new instances).
The lack of these optimizations will slow your program by a factor of 3 (very rounded guess that depends on your code).

Try some benchmarks that run for about 10 seconds. In the same run test with Vec2D, then Vec3D, then Vec2D, then Vec3D again. You will see this pattern:

- Vec2D ~10 seconds
- Vec3D ~30 seconds
- Vec2D ~30 seconds
- Vec3D ~30 seconds