# scala self-type: member of type parameter error

Tags: scala, self-type

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773611/proper-class-hierarchy-for-2d-and-3d-vectors).

Why does this code not compile, and how do I fix it?

```
trait Vec[V] { self:V =>
  def -(v:V):V
  def dot(v:V):Double

  def norm:Double = math.sqrt(this dot this)
  def dist(v:V):Double = (this - v).norm
}
```

The error is:

```
Vec.scala:6: error: value norm is not a member of type parameter V
  def dist(v:V):V = (this - v).norm
                               ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper solution is:

```
trait Vec[V <: Vec[V]] { self:V =>
  def -(v:V):V
  def dot(v:V):Double

  def norm:Double = math.sqrt(this dot this)
  def dist(v:V):Double = (this - v).norm
}
```

Props to [Debilski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200266/debilski) for the answer to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776864/scala-self-type-value-is-not-a-member-error/4777195#4777195).

Answer (score 6):

By changing the definition of - to

```
def -(v:V):Vec[V]
```

Comment: The self-type declaration is unidirectional.  It says that Vec[V] is a type conforming to type V, but not that V is a type conforming to Vec[V] (the actual semantics are more involved, since self-types aren't externally visible, but that's what it amounts to here).  Your original code had - returning V, but calling norm required a Vec[V].