# scala self-type: value is not a member error

Tags: scala, self-type

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774743/scala-self-type-member-of-type-parameter-error).

I'm trying to implement vectors in scala with a generic super class using self-types:

```
trait Vec[V] { self:V =>
  def /(d:Double):Vec[V] 
  def dot(v:V):Double

  def norm:Double = math.sqrt(this dot this)
  def normalize = self / norm
}
```

Here's an implementation of a 3D vector:

```
class Vec3(val x:Double, val y:Double, val z:Double) extends Vec[Vec3]
{
  def /(d:Double) = new Vec3(x / d, y / d, z / d)
  def dot(v:Vec3) = x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z 
  def cross(v:Vec3):Vec3 = 
  {
      val (a, b, c) = (v.x, v.y, v.z)
      new Vec3(c * y - b * z, a * z - c * x, b * x - a * y)
  }

  def perpTo(v:Vec3) = (this.normalize).cross(v.normalize)
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't compile:

```
Vec3.scala:10: error: value cross is not a member of Vec[Vec3]
  def perpTo(v:Vec3) = (this.normalize).cross(v.normalize)
                                        ^
```

What's going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Additionally, any references on self-types would be appreciated because I think these errors are cropping up from my lack of understanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get rid of all the nastiness, you have to specify that the type parameter `V` is a subclass of `Vec`.
Now you can just use `V` everywhere, because your trait knows that `V` inherits all `Vec[V]` methods.

```
trait Vec[V <: Vec[V]] { self: V =>
  def -(v:V): V
  def /(d:Double): V
  def dot(v:V): Double

  def norm:Double = math.sqrt(this dot this)
  def normalize: V = self / norm
  def dist(v: V) = (self - v).norm
  def nasty(v: V) = (self / norm).norm
}
```

Note the method `nasty` which won’t compile with [Easy Angel’s approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776864/scala-self-type-value-is-not-a-member-error/4776903#4776903).

Comment: Thank you. I believe this is the proper answer to my original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773611/proper-class-hierarchy-for-2d-and-3d-vectors . Would you mind posting there so I can give you points?

Answer (score 3):

I think, that method `/` in `Vec` should return `V` instead of `Vec[V]`:

```
trait Vec[V] { self:V =>
  def /(d:Double): V
  def dot(v:V):Double

  def norm:Double = math.sqrt(this dot this)
  def normalize = self / norm
}
```

method cross exists in `Vec3` (or in other words in `V`) but not in `Vec[V]`

Comment: What's the rule of thumb for when to use `Vec[V]` vs. `V`? The answer to the referenced question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774743/scala-self-type-member-of-type-parameter-error ) was exactly the opposite, change return type `V` to `Vec[V]`.

Comment: I think this current issue has nothing to do with sef-types. `normalize` will just return `Vec[V]` and method `cross` is not defined there, but in your previous issue `(this - v)` returns `V` and in this context `V` is not considered to be `Vec[V]` by compiller because self-type declaration is unidirectional (as mentioned in comments).