# define method to return type of class extending it

Tags: scala, types

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
trait A {
  def f(): ???_THE_EXTENDING CLASS
}
class C extends A {
  def f() = self
}
class D extends A {
  def f() = new D
}
class Z extends D {
  def f() = new Z
}
```

And the following would not compile, given the above code

```
class Bad1 extends A {
  def f() = "unrelated string"
}
class Bad2 extends A {
  def f() = new C // this means that you can't just define a type parameter on
                  // A like A[T <: A] with f() defined as f: T
}
class Bad3 extends D // f() now doesn't return the correct type
```

Is there a name for this kind of relationship? And how is it annotated/implemented in Scala?

## Edit

The following sort of works, as you can see:

```
scala> trait A {
     | def f: this.type 
     | }
defined trait A

scala> class C extends A {
     | def f = this 
     | }
defined class C

scala> class D extends A {
     | def f = new D
     | }
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : D
 required: D.this.type
       def f = new D
               ^
```

Is there a way to get around that?

## Edit 2

Using the second system, I can do this, which is good up to the definition of class D:

```
scala> trait A[T <: A[T]] { def f(): T }
defined trait A
// OR
scala> trait A[T <: A[T]] { self: T =>
     | def f(): T
     | }

scala> class C extends A[C] { def f() = new C }
defined class C

scala> class D extends C
defined class D

scala> (new D).f
res0: C = C@465fadce
```

Answer (score 15):

I'm afraid there is no possibility to know what is the extended class from the extending class.

The closest to what you'd like to have is something similar to Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) well known from C++.

```
trait A[T <: A[T]] {
  def f(): T;
}

class C extends A[C] {
  def f() = new C
}

class D extends A[D] {
  def f() = new D
}
```

Comment: This works better, but is there any way to get around the issue shown in the second edit?

Answer (score 7):

One thing that you can do, is to return type `this.type`:

```
trait A {
  def f(): this.type
}

class C extends A {
  def f() = this
}

class D extends A {
  def f() = this
}

class Z extends D {
  override def f() = this
  def x = "x"
}

println((new Z).f().x)
```

This can be useful for builders.

Comment: This doesn't work for every situation, although it's better than nothing. See edit in post for more details.

Comment: @aharon: Yeah, `this.type` is kind of singleton type. You can reed more about it [here](http://scalada.blogspot.com/2008/02/thistype-for-chaining-method-calls.html). So it's not for all possible scenarios...

Answer (score 5):

Here is another possible solution. It's combination of self type + type parameter:

```
trait A[T <: A[T]] { self: T =>
  def f(): T
}

class Z extends A[Z] {
  override def f() = new Z
  def x = "x"
}

println((new Z).f().x)
```

Here you can find more info about this solution:

[scala self-type: value is not a member error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776864/scala-self-type-value-is-not-a-member-error/4777195#4777195)

Comment: This works better, but is there any way to get around the issue shown in the second edit?