# Scala parameterized trait type - default to mixin super type?

Tags: scala, types

Hi I want to create a parameterized trait `trait Foo[T] // Foo[T]???` such that, in:

```
class Bar extends Foo
```

or

```
val b = new Bar() with Foo
```

"T" will automatically be "Bar" because that is type it is being mixed in to.  Not sure how I would go about that.

Answer (score 1):

From what I undestand of your problem, I'd say don't make `Foo` parametric and just use `this.type` where you would have used `T` in class `Foo`. See [How to use Scala's this typing, abstract types, etc. to implement a Self type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313139/how-to-use-scalas-this-typing-abstract-types-etc-to-implement-a-self-type) for a usage example.

However I must add that in practice it is often more practical to bite the bullet and just be explicit:

```
class Bar extends Foo[Bar]
```

This pattern even has a name: *Curiously Recurring Template Pattern* (mostly from the C++ literature).
See [define method to return type of class extending it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331722/define-method-to-return-type-of-class-extending-it) for an example in scala

Comment: well, what about:
    trait Foo {
        val things:Seq[this needs to be whatver type Foo was mixed in to]
    }