# Implementing trait PartialOrdered[T]

Tags: scala, traits, partial-ordering

As an exercise, I am supposed to implement a trait PartialOrdered[T].

```
trait PartialOrdered[T] {
  def below(that: T): Boolean
  def < (that: T): Boolean = (this below that) && !(that below this)  

  /* followed by other relations <=, >, >=, ==, .. */
}
```

A class K that extends this trait should have below implemented such that

```
a.below(b: K) = { true   if a <= b, 
                  false  in any other case
```

However, compiling gives the following error:

```
value below is not a member of type parameter T
def < (that: T): Boolean = (this below that) && !(that below this)
                                                        ^
```

So what am I missing? Thanks in advance

Edit: This is an example class Rectangle (in a coordinate system), with two opposing corners given, where a rectangle is below another if it is fully included

```
case class Rectangle (x1: Int, y1: Int, x2: Int, y2: Int) 
  extends PartialOrdered[Rectangle] {

  def below(r: Rectangle): Boolean = {
    val (rx, ry) = r.topLeft
    val (tx, ty) = this.topLeft
    tx >= rx && ty <= ry &&
    tx + this.width <= rx + r.width &&
    ty - this.height >= ry - r.height
  }

  def width: Int = {...}
  def height: Int = {...}
  def topLeft:(Int, Int) = {...}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell Scala that `T` is a subtype of `PartialOrdered[T]`:

```
trait PartialOrdered[T <: PartialOrdered[T]] { this: T =>
  def below(that: T): Boolean
  def < (that: T): Boolean = (this below that) && !(that below this)  

  /* followed by other relations <=, >, >=, ==, .. */
}
```

See also: [scala self-type: value is not a member error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4776864/200266)

Comment: That does work, but exceeds what I had learned before. I had tried something similar, which did not work with `<%` instead of `<:` Also what is the purpose of `this: T =>`?

Answer (score 1):

You need two concepts here. One is F-bounded polymorphism, the other is self-type constraints.

F-bounded polymorphism, without going into the underlying type theory, is essentially what makes binary operators work. You basically define a trait to have its parameter be a subtype of itself:

```
trait PartialOrdered[T <: PartialOrdered[T]] {
  this: T =>
    def below(that: T): Boolean
    def <(that: T): Boolean =
      (this below that) && !(that below this)
}
```

To make not just `this below that` work, but also `that below this`, we further need to constrain the self-type. This is done via `this: T =>`, so that the compiler knows that `this` is also an instance of `T`, and not just `PartialOrdered[T]`.

Then you define a class to use that trait. It needs to extend the trait with itself as the type parameter:

```
case class Pair(x: Double, y: Double) extends PartialOrdered[Pair] {
  def below(that: Pair) =
    x <= that.x && y <= that.y
}

object Program extends App {
  println(Pair(1, 2) < Pair(2, 0))
  println(Pair(1, 2) < Pair(1, 3))
  println(Pair(1, 2) < Pair(0, 2))
  println(Pair(1, 2) < Pair(2, 2))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`T` isn't necessarily an instance of `PartialOrdered[T]` so it doesn't have a below method. I think you meant

```
  def below(that: PartialOrdered[T]): Boolean
  def < (that: PartialOrdered[T]): Boolean = (this below that) && !(that below this)
```

?

Comment: I tried that, the compile will then ask for a proper implementation of `below` in the Rectangle class. However only want to compare Rectangles to Rectangles.

Comment: See Debilski's answer then.