# Scala: how to write method that returns object typed to implementation type of receiver

Tags: scala

I'm aware that case class inheritance is deprecated in Scala, but for the sake of simplicity, I've used it in the following example:

```
scala> case class Foo(val f: String) { def foo(g: String): Foo = { this.copy(f=g) }}
defined class Foo

scala> case class Bar(override val f: String) extends Foo(f)
warning: there were 1 deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
defined class Bar

scala> Bar("F")
res0: Bar = Foo(F)

scala> res0.foo("G")
res1: Foo = Foo(G)
```

So far, so good. What I really want, though, is to be able to write a method `foo()` in Foo that returns an object of type Bar when called on an object of type Bar, without having to reimplement the method in class Bar. Is there a way to do this in Scala?

Comment: Why loose your time to find a solution for a deprecated feature ? Your code may stop working with any of the next Scala releases, and you'll need to find another solution...

Comment: Case classes are not really relevant to the problem, they were just used for illustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: This does not create a new object but re-uses the `this` object. For general use, see [paradigmatic’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647626/scala-how-to-write-method-that-returns-object-typed-to-implementation-type-of-re/6648077#6648077).

For some reason, it does not work together with the `case class`’s `copy` method. (But admittedly, since `case class` inheritance should not be done anyway, the problem does not occur.). But for any other method, you do it with `this.type`.

```
case class Foo(val f: String) { def foo(g: String): this.type = { this }}

case class Bar(override val f: String) extends Foo(f)

Bar("F").foo("G")
res: Bar = Foo(F)
```

---

If you need the self-type variance in method arguments and method bodys (as opposed to return-type-only variance), you will need to go one step further and define

```
trait HasFoo[T <: HasFoo[T]] { this: T =>
  def foo(g:String): T
  def bar(g: T): T // here may follow an implementation
}
```

This will allow you to add proper method bodies to the `trait`. (See: [proper class hierarchy for 2D and 3D vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773611/proper-class-hierarchy-for-2d-and-3d-vectors))

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to know. Not to say that the other answers are bad, though.

Comment: this.type is something you want to be careful with: it describes the singleton type of the instance, not the most-specific non-singleton type as you might want. There is actually not a really good solution for this; the bound on the recursive type parameter isn't tight enough (i.e., given Foo[T <: Foo[T]], Bar extends Foo[Bar], it's possible to write Baz extends Foo[Bar]. My suggestion? Try a typeclass approach instead of implementing the method on the superclass.

Answer (score 6):

### builder approach

Yes, it can be done. A good example of that is the collections library.

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3) take 2
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> Array(1, 2, 3) take 2
res2: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)
```

See [The Architecture of Scala Collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html) to see how it was done.

**Edit**:
It uses two approaches to reuse implementations. The first is by using common traits and builders, and the other is using type classes.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Builder[A] {
  def apply(f: String): A
}
trait FooLike[A] {
  def builder: Builder[A]
  def f: String
  def genericCopy(f: String): A = builder(f)
  def map(fun: String => String): A = builder(fun(f))
}
case class Foo(f: String) extends FooLike[Foo] {
  def builder = new Builder[Foo] {
    def apply(f: String): Foo = Foo(f)
  }
}
case class Bar(f: String) extends FooLike[Bar] {
  def builder = new Builder[Bar] {
    def apply(f: String): Bar = Bar(f)
  }
}

scala> Foo("foo").genericCopy("something")
res0: Foo = Foo(something)

scala> Bar("bar").genericCopy("something")
res1: Bar = Bar(something)

scala> Foo("foo") map { _ + "!" }
res2: Foo = Foo(foo!)
```

The whole point of doing this, is so you can do something interesting at the common trait, like implementing common `map` in `FooLike`. It's hard to see the benefits with trivial code.

### type class approach

The benefit of using a type class is that you can add features to `Foo` and `Bar` even when you can't change them (like `String`).

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class Foo(f: String)
case class Bar(f: String)
trait CanCopy[A] {
  def apply(self: A, f: String): A
  def f(self: A): String
}
object CanCopy {
  implicit val fooCanCopy = new CanCopy[Foo] {
    def apply(v: Foo, f: String): Foo = v.copy(f = f)
    def f(v: Foo) = v.f
  }
  implicit val barCanCopy = new CanCopy[Bar] {
    def apply(v: Bar, f: String): Bar = v.copy(f = f)
    def f(v: Bar) = v.f
  }
  implicit val stringCanCopy = new CanCopy[String] {
    def apply(v: String, f: String): String = f
    def f(v: String) = v
  }

  def copy[A : CanCopy](v: A, f: String) = {
    val can = implicitly[CanCopy[A]]
    can(v, f)
  }

  def f[A : CanCopy](v: A) = implicitly[CanCopy[A]].f(v)
}

scala> CanCopy.copy(Foo("foo"), "something")
res1: Foo = Foo(something)

scala> CanCopy.f(Foo("foo"))
res2: String = foo

scala> CanCopy.copy(Bar("bar"), "something")
res3: Bar = Bar(something)

scala> CanCopy.copy("string", "something")
res4: java.lang.String = something
```

Comment: Note @Kris refers to the type class approach, since I only had link to the collections write up, and later added the code example for builder approach. I think it's case by case.

Answer (score 4):

The copy method is implemented by the compiler and it does not seem to belong a common trait. The easiest way to do it is to define a trait:

```
trait HasFoo[T] {
  def foo(g:String): T
}

case class Foo( f: String ) extends HasFoo[Foo] {
  def foo( g: String ) = copy(f=g)
}

case class Bar( f: String ) extends HasFoo[Bar] {
  def foo( g: String ) = copy(f=g)
}

scala> Bar("a").foo("b")
res7: Bar = Bar(b)

scala> Foo("a").foo("b")
res8: Foo = Foo(b)
```

Another option is to use type classes to provide an appropriate builder. But it wont save the number of typed characters.

Answer (score -3):

This solution doesn't require a separate trait.

```
class Bar

class Foo {
  def returnMyType[A](x:A) :A = { println(x); x }
}

val f = new Foo
val b = new Bar

val bReturned = f.returnMyType(b)

println(bReturned.getClass.getName)
```

Comment: This is the identity function and I think it has nothing to do with what the op asked for. You'd need to return an object of type `Foo` instead.

Comment: "What I really want, though, is to be able to write a method foo() in Foo that returns an object of type Bar when called on an object of type Bar" - i believe this is exactly what this does. The method body could of course be altered to change a property on the instance of f Boo.

Comment: at: moy Try to think about the difference of "called on" and "called with".